# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu Not Showing Correctly in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I've developed a website using Bootstrap, and it's ready for launch however over the past week, the dropdown menu isn't containing all of the data properly on Chrome:

[image]

http://demo.altru.co.uk

try hovering over KS1&KS2 in the top nav on chrome, I've tried on a few machines and it's the same issue. It works fine on firefox and internet explorer.

To make things simpler, I can tell you there is no special styling on the bootstrap, it's just standard, so my question is, is it a bug in chrome or an issue with my code that's only affecting chrome?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I've added an image of what I think you mean by `isn't containing all of the data`. Please bear in mind that once your issue is fixed, any others with the same issue will have no idea what your question is about, making answers useless for future visitors

Comment: Many thanks for that, I think because I am quite new it wouldn't let me add one but I appreciate your edit, hopefully someone can help.

Comment: Not a problem. StackOverflow is quite restrictive when you have low rep, although ideally you should've posted a JSFiddle demonstrating the problem in code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curiously, this is being caused by the `max-width` property set on the `<img>` tags in the menu. Assuming you're only using `.pad5right` in the menu, you need to modify your CSS to get rid of the max-width: 100%` set by Bootstrap:

```
.pad5right {
    padding-right: 5px;
    max-width: none;
}
```

A more general style for any menu would be this:

```
.dropdown-menu img {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Quite a strange issue which took a while to solve, and likely a bug in Chrome.

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you so much for your help. It's now fixed, and I had a suspicion it would be something to do with max-width but didn't think it would be the padding of the image. Genius!